# "Assignment to expression with array type" Error

Tags: c

Error while trying to assign a value to a string from another matrix of strings.

```
  last_command = buttonValues[i][j];
```

Solved by using :

```
strcpy (last_command, buttonValues[i][j]);
```

since you can't do that in C apparently.

Comment: Can you post more code? I don't see any mistakes in this line.

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: thanks for the comment! I just edited it to the full script. Sorry for the long script the problem occurs exactly in the show_buttons() function

Comment: After you clarified that neither the mentioned line in your code, nor GTK is involved in your problem you might adapt the title and tags of your question.

Comment: @Gerhardh Done :D thanks for notifying me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the line above

```
 last_command = buttonValues[i][j];
```

and I thought it's in this line

```
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(buttons[i][j]), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(solve_button_callback), 0);
```

I had this bad c# habit of assigning strings directly :D 
solved it by using this: (duh)

```
strcpy (last_command, buttonValues[i][j]);
```

Sorry for the tedious question and thanks everyone for the help.